# Jetpack compose definition

Tags: android, kotlin

May somebody please explain to me what is jetpack ,or what jetpack compose is? as if I was a 5 year old.I have tried youtube tutorials just can't seem to get.Also please explain how do I get it work on android studio,does it come pre installed or do I need to download it,please explain as simple as possible.

Comment: Jetpack Compose is Android’s modern toolkit for building native UI. It simplifies and accelerates UI development on Android. Quickly bring your app to life with less code, powerful tools, and intuitive Kotlin APIs.

Comment: On Android, the UI was traditionally created in an XML file and then "inflated" in the code (e.g., in an activity or fragment). Jetpack Compose is the replacement of the XML approach. It lets you define the UI in Kotlin, which is a much more type-safe way to do it. And, as I understand it, it has a (at least slightly) different way of connecting the backend to the frontend (the UI). How exactly Jetpack Compose works I'm not sure, as I don't have really any experience with it. Check out https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial

Comment: Also see https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose

Answer (score 0):

Compose is a UI that is declarative, which means we can code the UI with our Kotlin file. In XML we had layout files where we used to connect them with our activities and fragments basically the design was in different file and functionality was in different.
But with compose those both are in same file.
And Why jetpack is that google has a jetpack library and compose comes under jetpack components so its named Jetpack compose.
You also have Compose Multiplatform as a Multiplatform library too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**What is Jetpack?**
Jetpack is a suite of libraries to help developers follow best practices, reduce boilerplate code, and write code that works consistently across Android versions and devices so that developers can focus on the code they care about.
In other words, Google has provided some libraries which can be used to make development easy in a standard way.

**What is Jetpack compose?**
Jetpack Compose is Android’s recommended modern toolkit for building native UI.
It is declarative programming approach for building UI. Earlier we used imperative approach (using xml and updating UI with steps defined in Java or Kotlin code)
 In compose we define UI using kotlin code.

**What is declarative approach vs imperative approach?**
**Declarative**: "Make an omelette with eggs, cheese, and vegetables, whisk together and cook until firm."
**Imperative**: "Crack two eggs into a bowl, whisk them until blended, pour into a heated pan, add cheese and vegetables, cook until the edges start to set, then fold and serve."

Declarative focuses on the end result, while imperative outlines the process step by step.

**Please explain how do I get it work on android studio, does it come pre installed or do I need to download it.** 
You need to install the compose dependencies in the build.gradle(app), follow below link for the same.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup